# Docker commands failing although docker is running

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I installed `docker` on `Win-10 Pro VM` and it worked perfectly for a day. 
Next day machine was restarted and docker start failed with error:

> No activity detected on VM, aborting    at
>   Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[]
>   parameters) in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeClient.cs:line
>   36    at Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx,
>   Boolean showWelcomeWindow, Boolean executeAfterStartCleanup) in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line
>   92    at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.b__0()
>   in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line
>   155    at Docker.WPF.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<.ctor>b__1() in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.cs:line 59

I restarted docker and it started without any issues instantly. But now all docker commands are failing:

> PS C:> docker ps error during connect: Get
>   http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.39/containers/json:  open
>   //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In
>   the default  daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must
>   be run elevated to connect.  This error may also indicate that the
>   docker daemon is not running.

I have tried:

- Resetting the docker to factory default
- Reinstalling docker
- Restarting the VM
- Restarting docker with administrator priviledges
- and so on...

But nothing worked. Any idea how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I had a similar issue after updating to a newer docker version, when I detected more then one instance in the autostart. I deactivated all autostart docker and now I only start docker from the desktop, when I need it. With that my docker is more stable.

Comment: unfortunately..this also didn't help... :(